# How can I pass two parameters from API endpoints and receive in "PHP" like: (array_key_exists("getId", $_GET)){}?

Tags: php, rest

In this example, we only receive one value(id) from URL: But I need to receive two values(Id, and Date) from URL: So, How can I receive?

```
if (array_key_exists("purchaseReturnId", $_GET)) {
    $purchaseReturnId = $_GET['purchaseReturnId'];
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You have an API endpoint, GET, you pass some parameters there. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Read those params? Are there always two and always same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

**url endpoints**

```
http://localhost:3030/?purchaseReturnId=3&date=15-03-2021
```

Value receive from this url...

```
if (array_key_exists("purchaseReturnId", $_GET)) {
    $purchaseReturnId = $_GET['purchaseReturnId'];
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    var_dump($purchaseReturnId, $date);
}
```